# saturated model

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Suppose you have a saturated model N of a complete theory T without finite models. How is it possibile to construct a proper saturated elementary substructure of N of the same cardinality of N ?
I tried to use a construction similar to the donward lowheneim-skolem theorem but I can not prove the saturation ...

Comment: Try, instead, to give a proper elementary superstructure of the same cardinality which is also saturated.  Then check why this is equivalent to what you want, using the fact that saturated models of the same cardinality must be isomorphic.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I think that the existence of satured superstructure of the same cardinality is related to that the cardinality of N is an inaccessible cardinal using

Comment: the theorem : if k is an inaccessible infinite cardinal and the cardinality of N is less than k, then N admits a saturated elementary superstructure with cardinality egual to k.

Comment: You certainly don't need to use inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: By the way, this question is really a better fit for math.stackexchange, since it's not really research level.  At some point I expect others will come by and close this question.

Comment: Take any elementary extension $M$ of $N$ of the same cardinaility.  There is an elementary embedding of $M$ into $N$.  Thus $N$ has an isomorphic proper elementary submodel, or, equivalently an isomorphic proper elementary extentsion.

Comment: crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227098/elementary-substructure-in-a-satureted-model